# How to read with a TcpClient until the other side closes or we stop in .Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, sockets

I have a listener that returns a TcpClient that must read data until the other side closes or until we stop.

I have created a simple Form with two buttons. One starts one connection and the other stops it.

The problem is that when I have a IOException due to the timeout of the Read the socket is closed and I cannot communicate with it again. I cannot reconnect it as is the other side the one to establish the connection.

Just execute the code and telnet to the port 502, wait one second and you will see the problem.

How would you do that?

```
Public Class Form1

Private m_listener As Net.Sockets.TcpListener
Private m_client As Net.Sockets.TcpClient
Private m_stopping As Boolean

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim data As Byte()
    Dim dataLength As Integer

    ReDim data(512)

    m_listener = New Net.Sockets.TcpListener(Net.IPAddress.Any, 502)
    m_listener.Start()
    m_client = m_listener.AcceptTcpClient()

    m_client.GetStream().ReadTimeout = 1000
    m_client.GetStream().WriteTimeout = 1000

    While Not m_stopping
        Try
            dataLength = m_client.GetStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)
            If dataLength = 0 Then
                MsgBox("Disconnected")
            Else
                MsgBox(dataLength.ToString() & " bytes received")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception When TypeOf (ex) Is TimeoutException OrElse (Not ex.InnerException Is Nothing AndAlso TypeOf (ex.InnerException) Is Net.Sockets.SocketException AndAlso DirectCast(ex.InnerException, Net.Sockets.SocketException).ErrorCode = 10060)
            ''# Just retry
        End Try
    End While
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    m_stopping = True
End Sub
End Class
```

This question is related to the question:
[How to close a TcpClient when the other end has been closed in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973956/how-to-close-a-tcpclient-when-the-other-end-has-been-closed-in-net)

FINALLY: The real problem is that to know when a client has closed the connection I must do a Read and check for a return of 0. If the Read has infinite Timeout the call will block and I will not be able to end the application until the Read returns something, if the read has a finite Timeout I can have a TimeoutException and then the Socket will be closed. So ... HOW THE HELL I'M SUPPOSED TO KNOW WHEN THE OTHER PART HAS CLOSED THE CONNETION? I can not believe that something so "easy" is so hard.

Comment: Is expected that if someone puts a down vote explains why, because if not the down vote is completely useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution. What has to be done is to do a Read() with timeout set to infinite and when you need to unblock that Read call you just need to call to Close() and the Read() will unblock.

Comment: fantastic, this is finally the solution that worked for me, too.  I'm glad you posted it!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to `Read` from the stream and catch a `TimeoutException`, you could check the [`Available`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.available.aspx) property to know whether there is data to be read. That way the `TimeoutException` won't happen, and you will still be able to reuse the `TcpClient`

Comment: If I do that I will never know when the remote host closes the connection because to do that I need to do a Read and it will return 0.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on the result of Read to detect wether the connection is closed... you should use the Connected property instead

Comment: That's not true. The Connected property is only updated after a Read or a Write so if I never do a Read the Connected will remain True forever.

Comment: I've spent a lot of time trying to find an answer to getting read to properly timeout, and I can't for the life of me understand why anyone would recommend a busy polling approach as this. The proper way using sockets is to use read with timeouts. Now of course somebody without a clue at Microsoft appears to not have implemented this functionality properly with the TcpClient class. Why on earth would they close the socket because of a read timeout? Read timeouts have been done by every other OS I've ever programmed with including windows. Microsoft needs to fix their code to work properly.